# How to add Ultra Wide viewfinder behind regular camera

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, avcapturesession

I’m trying to replicate the default camera on iPhone. Where it uses the Ultra Wide camera to show extra space at the top and bottom of the default camera viewfinder. Is it possible to do this?

My Project is using a pretty standard UIKit implementation. I searched around and asked ChatGPT but to no avail